# C++ MatLab like constructor overloading

Tags: c++, matlab, constructor

I have a class Sparse_Matrix that allows me to efficiently work with sparse matrices.

I would like to instantiate a specific matrix by using specific (idiomatic) keywords such as Upper, Identity, etc.

This is my class declaration (namespace matrix)

```
template <typename T>
class Sparse_Matrix
{

  private:
  int rows;
  int cols;
  std::vector<int> col;
  std::vector<int> row;
  std::vector<T> value;
  ...
```

Is there a way to get an pre-initialized object?

```
 Sparse_Matrix<int> = Eye(3);
```

would return a 3-by-3 identity matrix.

I have looked at constructor idioms but those require some soft of static type that is not compatible with my class (though I am open to suggestions).

I have also tried this code:

```
template <typename T>
Sparse_Matrix<T> Eye(int size)
{
  Sparse_Matrix<T> ma;
  ma.IdentityMatrix(size);
  std::cout << "Eye!" << std::endl;
  return ma;
}
```

...

```
Sparse_Matrix<int> blah = Eye(10);
```

but to no avail.

Thank you,

SunnyBoyNY

Comment: What does "but to no avail." mean specifically?

Comment: The compiler error is : `no matching function for call to "Eye(int)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one place in C++ where template parameters can be deduced based on how the expression is used: a user-defined conversion operator.

```
struct Eye
{
    int size;
    explicit Eye(int requestedSize) : size(requestedSize) {}

    template<typename T>
    operator SparseMatrix<T>() const { SparseMatrix<T> ma; ma.IdentityMatrix(size); return ma; }
};
```

Now you can write

```
Sparse_Matrix<int> blah = Eye(10);
```

Comment: It seems that my GCC compilers encounters an error : `error : ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Eye' with no type`. and `error: only declaration of constructors can be explicit`.

Comment: @SunnyBoyNY: Then you misspelled something.  It compiles quite well -- http://ideone.com/C1CcUG (using vector instead of `SparseMatrix` which I don't have a definition for)

Comment: Of course I made a spelling error - I renamed the struct to Eye2 but did not rename the Eye after the `explicit` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Having a function that constructs your object is a good strategy.  In your example, one solution would be specifically to tell `Eye` the type:

```
Sparse_Matrix<int> blah = Eye<int>(10);
```

Sometimes these functions are static within the class for clarity:

```
template<typename T>
class Sparse_Matrix
{
public:
    static Sparse_Matrix<T> Eye(...) {...}
};
```

In this case, you would call:

```
Sparse_Matrix<int> blah = Sparse_Matrix<int>::Eye(10);
```

Comment: Well, you don't actually need to, you just need to add a deducible context.

Comment: @JaredC It looks like I have just been missing the constructor <>. Now, why would these functions be declared static?

Comment: @SunnyBoyNY `<>` is not a constructor.  It is the syntax for specifying the type `T` of your `Eye` function.  You don't have to make the function static.  Some people prefer the clarity of the function belonging to the class its constructing, and others don't.  But if `Eye` were a static member function you could have access to private members if you needed.

Comment: @JaredC I see. I have added this to the code: `static Sparse_Matrix<T> Eye(int size);` and `template <typename T> 
Sparse_Matrix<T> Sparse_Matrix<T>::Eye(int size)
{ ... }` and now it is possible to compile this line in the main function : `Sparse_Matrix<int> blah = Sparse_Matrix<int>::Eye(10);`

Comment: I find it interesting that the compiler does not fill out the second template <> automatically based on the first type.

Comment: @SunnyBoyNY  See Ben's answer. There's a lot of good reasons for this, but in most cases its probably just too difficult (your example here is a rather simple one).

Comment: @JaredC Thank you for your answers. While I would like to upvote your answer, I cannot since my reputation is too low. Ben has provided the exact answer I was looking for. Good luck and thanks again!